# Spark Python creating new Dataframe from Dataframe loop setting field NULL based on decision

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe

So I have a question regarding how to go about programming something in Spark with Python. Please keep in mind I am not asking you to code it, I am asking for how to do it. I am so stuck as to how to do it in Spark. Any help or ideas would be REALLY appreciated.

1) Take all rows from database and create pyspark.sql.DataFrame **- DONE**
2) Transform rows in said DataFrame **- DONE**
3) Create a Broadcast variable from DataFrame only two columns [ID, GROUPID] **- DONE**
reason for broadcast variable is for Partioning/clustering.
4) Loop the DataFrame and search the broadcast variable to see if this iterations GROUPID exists with any OTHER ID. If NO record found then NULL this iterations GROUPID

EXAMPLE: Broadcast variable

```
+-------+---------+
|     ID|  GROUPID|
+-------+---------+
| 363345|    95124|
| 363356|    95124|
| 363359|    88896|
| 363361|    50012|<===== only one of this groupid in Broadcast variable
| 375362|    62551|
| 363487|    62551|
| 363489|    88896|
+-------+---------+
```

DataFrame (300K+ rows) needed to be looped and check the broadcast variable to null GROUPID

```
+------+---------+-------+----+-------+------------+
|    ID|PRODUCTID|    ARM|SORT|GROUPID|        NAME|
+------+---------+-------+----+-------+------------+
|363345|   523927|5888208|  10|  95124|Enalapril...|
|363356|   523927|5888390|  10|  95124|LISINOPL5...|
|363359|   523927|5888444|  10|  88896|RANTUDEUR...|
|363361|   523927|5888450|  10|  50012|POLYALFA1...|<===== This record GROUPID should be nulled, only one record found in Broadcast variable
|375362|   523927|5888527|  10|  62551|POLAUTFA2...|
|375360|   523927|5894976|  10|   null|ENCERACAF...|
|363487|   523927|5905131|  10|  62551|Poly Alco...|
|363488|   523927|5905148|  10|   null|     Poly...|
|363489|   523927|5905160|  10|  88896|Eapril688...|
|363495|   523927|5909258|  10|   null| Eapril77...|
+------+---------+-------+----+-------+------------+
```

```
CREATING the DataFrame
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (363345, 523927, 5888208, 10, 95124, 'Enalapril...'), 
            (363356, 523927, 5888390, 10, 95124, 'LISINOPL5...'), 
            (363359, 523927, 5888444, 10, 88896, 'RANTUDEUR...'), 
            (363361, 523927, 5888450, 10, 50012, 'POLYALFA1...'), 
            (375362, 523927, 5888527, 10, 62551, 'POLAUTFA2...'), 
            (375360, 523927, 5894976, 10,  None, 'ENCERACAF...'), 
            (363487, 523927, 5905131, 10, 62551, 'Poly Alco...'), 
            (363488, 523927, 5905148, 10,  None, 'Poly...'), 
            (363489, 523927, 5905160, 10, 88896, 'Eapril688...'), 
            (363495, 523927, 5909258, 10,  None, 'Eapril77...')
        ],
        ['ID', 'PRODUCTID', 'ARM', 'SORT', 'GROUPID', 'NAME']
    )
```

Creating the Broadcast variable

```
ID_GROUPID_Dictionary = {}    
for row in df.rdd.collect():
    if(row['GROUPID'] != None):
        ID_GROUPID_Dictionary[int(row['ID'])] = int(row['GROUPID']) 
df_FROMDB_READONLY_BROADCAST = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(ID_GROUPID_Dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

using broadcast for this seems over the top there are a ton of other options to use here,
an example can be aggregateByKey(a dataset function) your data by groupid and then run a flatmap checking if the size is bigger then 2 . if smaller then 2 change the value to null if no then return all values as is.
you can do this stuff in sql and dataframe or with RDD. depends on you but your code will be way cleaner. for any question feel free to comment my answer.

Comment: LlYa,

I understand about the broadcast variable being more than needed so lets take that out of the equation and go with your tip. I have pondered what you mean with using aggregateByKey() but I need all the columns after from the original DataFrame. So combining them to a Key, Value form wont work in this situation. Sorry for being so dense but there is something I am failing to see. Could you help clarify it for me.

Comment: read about aggregatebykey, it doesnt work like groupBy , if you know about sql you should understand how it works if not you should probably read about it but I see no reason why it wont work for you.

Answer (score 0):

By the way this is the way that I solved this issue. @Ilya Thanks for the note. Let me know if anyone sees a better way.

```
GROUPID_countList = df.groupBy(df.GROUPID).count().collect()                   
replaceGROUPIDUDF = udf(lambda x: None if x is None else GROUPIDCount(x), IntegerType())      
def GROUPIDCount(grpid):
    for x in GROUPID_countList:            
        if(x["GROUPID"] == grpid): #DEBUG print("{} - {} : {} ".format(x["GROUPID"], grpid, x["count"] ))
            return x["count"]             
    return 0

df = df.withColumn('GROUPID_null', (when(replaceGROUPIDUDF(df['GROUPID']) < 2, lit(None).cast("string"))
                                        .otherwise(df['GROUPID']))) \
                            .drop('GROUPID') \
                            .withColumnRenamed('GROUPID_null', 'GROUPID')
```